# how to create environment variables recognized by OSX gui

Tags: terminal, keyboard, finder, bash, alias

I use a lot of aliases in my ~/.bash_profile.. just to make my navigation easier and so on.

I was wondering if I can make environment variables recognizable by OSX at a gui level.. for example if I open a finder window, and click <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>, I'd like to enter something like this
[image]

where $dev is defined as `/path/to/my/dev/folder`

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possible, but messy in recent versions of macOS -- see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite#26586170) for details. But it won't do what you want, because the environment variable substitutions you're used to are done by the shell; most GUI inputs (like the Finder's Go To Folder command) are not parsed by a shell, so no environment variable substitution is performed. The Go To Folder operation in your screenshot isn't looking for a variable named "dev", it's looking for a folder literally named "$dev".